# Can not install laravel

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I can not install Laravel in this way:

```
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist ~5.0
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist 5.0
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel blog
```

Response in console:

```
Could not find package laravel\laravel with stability stable.
```

or

```
Could not find package laravel\laravel with version ~5.0.
```

I'm trying do this in another way like that:

```
 php laravel new blog
```

Project doest not exist after crafting project or I have info in console:

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 192.241.224.13 port 80: Timed out
```

What is wrong with this stupid composer ? :(

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using forward-slashes (`/`) or back-slashes (`\\`)? Your error messages indicate the latter, while your entered commands indicate the former. (And it should only be forward-slashes)

Comment: @ChrisForrence - I'm on Windows 10. I changes /  \ nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can install laravel in those ways. May be it's your network problem.

But there are other way to do so..

Go to [laravel github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) page and sort it with branch or tag and download it as zip. then unzip and from inside folder run

```
php composer.phar install.
```

You can get it work.